# How to get modal window location change event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, external, modal-dialog

I have modal popup of external site using jquery 
The external site is a login

After completion of the login the modal window will redirect to a site.

I want to:
i) identify when the modal has redirected (login complete)
ii) capture the modal url to acquire parameters from the url.

How do i do this in jquery methods & javascript

Answer (score 0):

If it's an external site, you can't, due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can't sneak a look into other sites' documents, even if you opened them in a modalDialog or in-page iframe. It would be a security hole if you could steal parameters from the URL.

You can't repurpose another site's login process for your own ends unless that site deliberately exposes an interface to let you do it.